# If my facebook application is misconfigured, how do I find out more?

Tags: facebook, request

My facebook app simply has apprequests raised from my site via FB.ui. Unfortunately clicking the request notification yields:

```
Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.
```

How do I find out where the misconfiguration lies?

Comment: Yeah, appID is corrent, and FB.init seems to work ok.

Comment: which of the options have you selected in the basic settings of your app? i mean "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In facebook, under app roles, give app admin rights to the account which receives the notification. (I set up a test FB account for this).

It then gives you extra information e.g.

[image]

Comment: @iandyayman i am experiencing same problem. When I remove FB android app, it gets fixed. Kindly can you explain a bit more?