# FB.getLoginStatus works for me but not my tester

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm testing an app that works fine for me on my computer, but when my friend tests it doesn't properly load on his computer. He gets the permission screen, selects the permissions and then the rest won't load.

I've discovered that FB.getLoginStatus is not returning anything on his end. It shouldn't be a browser issue because I've had him try it in Firefox (which I use). Also it shouldn't be anything to do with his facebook account because I had him log in as me and test it with the same result.

writeDisplayConsole on my end writes "connected" etc., but for my friend nothing is written about the connection, which means there was no response from getLoginStatus. The rest of the app shows fine but the welcomePlayer function doesn't execute.

Anyone know what the issue could be?

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      writeDisplayConsole('FB LSTATUS: ' + response.status);
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
          gPlayerFBID = response.authResponse.userID;
          writeDisplayConsole('User ID:'+ gPlayerFBID);
          welcomePlayer(gPlayerFBID);
      }
  });
```

Comment: What's the error message? What are trying to show? What code are you using? My crystal ball has a loose wire, so I can't see what's wrong on your end **at the moment**.

Comment: Edited to show the part in question.

Comment: Did you notice your else is disconnected from the if?

Comment: Gah sorry, haven't looked at this part of the code for awhile. That was from another if statement above checking a boolean to use facebook or not, so that's not the issue. (edited out)

Comment: So you assume both `response` and `response.status` are defined on the callback. Why? Have you tried checking for that value? Are you running this call **after** performing a login? Is your friend blocking popups whilst you're allowing them?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the user tested it while logged in to my account. FB.getLoginStatus is checking if you're already logged in, which he is. The response is defined in the facebook API, I'm not sure what you mean about checking the value?

Comment: I should clarify that this works on my computer and as I mentioned the response.status shows connected for me, so it must be defined properly.

Comment: 'connected' means the user is authenticated on your app and is logged into fb (with a valid access token to your app) - it may also return 'unknown'. Have you considered there may be an error on your logic flow? Have you tried logging out of FB, removing the permissions to your app and then testing it? Also, are you using OpenGraph or just the login?

Comment: It returns 'connected' for me. It doesn't return anything, not even unknown, with my friend. I've tried removing permissions, that brings you to a page saying the app is misconfigured. This is not what's happening to my friend who has given it permission. Also consider that he also logged into MY facebook account to test it. I'm not using OpenGraph yet just the login.

Comment: *I've tried removing permissions, that brings you to a page saying the app is misconfigured.* -- so there you are, this shouldn't happen

Comment: To be clear, when I mentioned *removing permissions* I meant removing a user's permissions to a particular FB app.

Comment: Yes, I removed the permissions to the FB app from the facebook app settings menu. I should have mentioned, the app misconfigured screen comes up after I remove permissions and then load the app and deny the permissions. If I remove permissions, reload the app and give permission then the app loads normally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901635/if-my-facebook-application-is-misconfigured-how-do-i-find-out-more

Comment: That's not the issue. As I mentioned, that error only occurs when you deny the app permission. The problem we're talking about is when the user grants permission and the app doesn't load properly. Anyway, I found the problem, it's because my friend had "secure browsing" enabled in his settings. With that disabled, the app works fine. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get my friend to disable "secure browsing" under his facebook settings because the app is not on a secure connection. After disabling securing browsing, the app works fine.