# facebook sharing video not playing

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

i am using  codova 2.9.0. i give option to sharing video and image in facebook via cordova facebook connect plugin. Shared successfully. but when i click video in facebook page i got this error

**Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.**

and it have two buttons **Go Home** and **Find Another App**

this is my code:

```
 FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: '',
    caption: '',
    description: des,
    link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/mobile-start/',
   source: postimage,
   picture: url,
    actions: [{ name: 'Get Started', link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/mobile-start/' }],
  }, 
  function(response) {
    console.log('publishStory UI response: ', response);
  });
```

what i missing?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901635/if-my-facebook-application-is-misconfigured-how-do-i-find-out-more

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution [Here](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/chapter_facebook.html)
What you need to do is

1. The first line is a modification of the HTML head tag. This is required in your page for either active or passive sharing.
2. The first meta tag, shown in bold, is required for passive sharing, because you must have a Facebook app for passive sharing, as detailed in [Passive App Setup.](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/tasks/facebook_passive_app_setup.html#facebook_passive_app_setup)
3. Highlighted in italics are values that you must supply to this template.

So meta tag code will be like

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<!-- The following tag is required for passive sharing -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="yourFacebookAppIdHere" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="yourTitleHere" />
<meta property="og:description" content="yourDescriptionHere" />
<meta property="og:url" content="yourURLwithTheEmbeddedVideo">
<meta property="og:image" content="yourImageUrlHere"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="yourUrlHere" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="yourSecureUrlHere" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=YourOoyalaEmbedCodeHere&keepEmbedCode=true" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url” content="https://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=YourOoyalaEmbedCodeHere&keepEmbedCode=true" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: @kathir, if you find it solved, please accept it by clicking on tick mark.

It will give reputation to both of us and please vote for the solution.

Thank you